# Instead of continue, rerun function

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm wondering how to do the following in Python.
If I have a function with a `for` loop, it is possible to with an if statement to skip certain numbers.

This is an implementation of fisher-yates d got from activestate.com.

```
import random

def shuffle(ary):
    a=len(ary)
    b=a-1
    for d in range(b,0,-1):
      e=random.randint(0,d)
      if e == d:
            continue
      ary[d],ary[e]=ary[e],ary[d]
    return ary
```

Now `continue` simply goes to the next value for d. How can I, instead of doing `continue`, rerun the function with the original parameter `ary`?

Note that the function is just some example code, I'm curious on how to do this in general.
Also, maintaining a copy of the array might not be possible if the list is big, so thats not really a solution imo.

Comment: The list is not edited in place...

Comment: Do you want to continue in the original loop after you “restarted” the function? I.e. do you want to have recursion, or do you just want to abort the current function and start over?

Comment: @gioi I assume the list would be edited in place in the `"do something to the list"` part.

Comment: What _exactly_ are you doing to the list in the `else` branch? Adding/removing elements? Which ones?

Comment: I've found an example that is actually pretty close to the code I wrote. It's an implementation of the Fisher-Yates shuffle. I've updated the code in the start post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common recursive pattern.  However, your case is a little different than usual because here you need to make a *copy* of your input list to use when you recurse if the shuffling fails.:

```
import random

def shuffle(ary):
    initial = ary[:]
    a=len(ary)
    b=a-1
    for d in range(b,0,-1):
      e=random.randint(0,d)
      if e == d:
            return shuffle(initial)
      ary[d],ary[e]=ary[e],ary[d]
    return ary


ary = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print shuffle(ary)
```

Also note that [Wikipedia gives a (non-recursive) python implementation of the very similar Sattolo's algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

```
from random import randrange

def sattoloCycle(items):
    i = len(items)
    while i > 1:
        i = i - 1
        j = randrange(i)  # 0 <= j <= i-1
        items[j], items[i] = items[i], items[j]
    return
```

If I read the article correctly, to re-acquire Fisher-Yates, you'd just do one simple change:

```
from random import randrange

def FisherYates(items):
    i = len(items)
    while i > 1:
        i = i - 1
        j = randrange(i+1)  # 0 <= j <= i
        items[j], items[i] = items[i], items[j]
    return
```

Comment: No this doesnt work. If I make `ary = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and replace the `continue` with `return shuffle(ary)` I get, among others the result `[5, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1]`. I don't think that should happen since the `4` remains in the same place, and if I understand the code correctly that should not be the case.

Comment: Note that the example code has changed to an implementation i just found, but the problem is the same.

Comment: From what I can see, the problem remains that with `return shuffle(ary)` you are rerunning `shuffle()` with an already modified `ary`. And thats not the behaviour I'm looking for.

Comment: @Mythio -- I didn't see your updated code until just a minute ago.  See my update.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at the Sattolo algorithm. The solution you provide however, means keeping a copy of the original array. I'd like to know if its possible to avoid that, for instance because of memory constraints. Is that possible?

Comment: @Mythio -- See the final code snippet I posted.  That won't keep an extra copy.  If you're going to do this recursively (which I don't suggest), then you need the copy.

Comment: Ok, from what I can see it's not really possible than, only in specific cases. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(list):
    len(list)-1
    for i in range(len(list)-1,0,-1):
      e= randint(0,i)
      while e > i:
            e= randint(0,i)
      "do something to the list"
    return array
```

?

Answer (score 0):

you can copy the parameter to a temp variable. then call the function with the temp variable and use return;

```
def function(list):
listCopy = list;
    len(list)-1
    for i in range(len(list)-1,0,-1):
      e= randint(0,i)
      if e > i:
            return function(listCopy)
      else
            "do something with the list"
    return array
```

Comment: If `list` will be changed in-place, `listCopy` will be changed as well.

Comment: BTW, what are those semicolons?

Comment: @poke: exactly, you could use `listCopy = list(list)` to create a truly new list, but memory wise this is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(list):
    for i in (a for a in range(len(list)-1,0,-1) if randint(0,a) > a):
        #do something with list
    #do something else with remainder.
```

Not exactly what you asked for. Just wanted to remind you of this possibility.